# Can photons move in circles?

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics

A photon can travel between two points A and B in a straight line. However, there is a chance it will go in a slightly curved path. Is there a chance the photon will turn around? Does this mean that photons can go in circles?

Comment: Photons don't travel on paths, at all. That's just a poorly thought out physical image that leads to more problems than it solves. Can light be bent? Of course. Your internet connection runs trough glass fibers which do just that. You have just been messaging us trough light running in curves.

Comment: To clarify I'm not talking about bending light. I'm talking about light moving through a vacuum via multiple interfering paths and asking if one of them goes in a loop. Each path has a small chance of being the path a photon takes.

Comment: I don't think fiber-optic cable is a good example anyway.   Light still travels in a straight line, it just reflects off the side and the reflection follows the curve of the fiber.   http://cdn4.explainthatstuff.com/fiber-optics-simulation.jpg   from:  http://www.explainthatstuff.com/fiberoptics.html

Comment: @userLTK: Single mode fiber does not work that way. It can not be understood by discrete internal reflections.

Comment: That's not how quantum mechanics works. It's a picture that stems from path integrals, which are a mathematical  starting point of defining perturbation series.

Comment: I'd guess you're thinking about [Feynmann's path integral formalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation). If so self intersecting paths would not be included, but all non-self intersecting paths of any shape would be included. Note however that this is a computational device and doesn't literally mean the electron travels along all possible paths.

Comment: So would you be willing to say its physically impossible for a photon to turn around in a vacuum?

Comment: Well, I take back what I said about fiber-optic cable then.   I thought that was how it worked.

Comment: @userLTK It's not a bad model for large diameter, generic fibers, but single mode fibers have many desirable features and are used almost exclusively in long distance communications. And single-mode propagation has to be understood in terms of wave-guide physics.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple explanation of where it can happen:    [Photon Sphere](http://apod.nasa.gov/htmltest/gifcity/pscirc.html)   and a more complex one:   [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere).   A photon-sphere can exist around a Neutron Star too.   But a pure circular path is impossible, just as a pure circular orbit is impossible.  There's always going to be some eccentricity to any orbit and in the case of light, it will either quickly escape the photon sphere or fall into the object.

A 180 degree turn around is certainly possible, but only with a Neutron Star or Black hole.   Nothing else is massive enough.